# What is the fastest way to Delete Data from Azure Storage Table?

Tags: azure

I have 1 Table in Azure Table Storage and I want to delete data from this table which is older then 90 days Is any easy way is there to delete data automatically from Azure Table Storage?

Any ideas how to do this most effectively? Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe the table structure? What's the value contained in `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` field?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You need to query using Partition Key and Row Key and delete them.

Just query by Partition Key may not result in the fastest query as the data is spread among several servers.

Comment: I would not recommend deleting the table as the requirement is to delete data older than 90 days and not all data.

Comment: Your answer assumes the date of creation is somehow stored in the partition or row key. If that is not the case your answer is not valid!